# How do I add all root principals from an organization to an SNS access policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sns, identity-management

I want to grant publish access to an SNS topic to all root principals from my organization, similarly to what's described in the AWS Blog [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/control-access-to-aws-resources-by-using-the-aws-organization-of-iam-principals/#:%7E:text=Example%3A%20Restrict%20access%20to%20only%20principals%20from%20my%20organization).

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowPublish",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root"
  },
  "Action": "sns:Publish",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:........",
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-xxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
```

The principals field doesn't allow wildcards in the arn, and if I wildcard it for all, it gives access to other principals from the accounts as well.

Is there a way to achieve this without explicitly specifying the principal of each account?